# To apply two functions to multiply variables with aggregate() in r

Tags: r

There is a data frame x with 5753 observations of 4 variables.

The column names are: date, Depth, var1, and var2.  I converted date and Depth to factor before performing aggregate().

I wanted to calculate average and standard deviation to 2 variables with grouping by date and Depth.

When applying `aggregate(x[,3:4], by = list(x$date, x$Depth), FUN = function(x) c(avg = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), SD= sd))`, I got average of var1 and average of var 2 grouping by date and Depth, but I did not get SD.

When applying `aggregate(. ~ date+Depth, data = x, FUN = function(x) c(avg = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), SD= sd))`, I got an error message: "***Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : no rows to aggregate***".

After counting NA in two column, I found out that there are 5622 NA in var1, 5049 NA in var2.  I donot want to remove NA before applying aggregate() yet.

My questions are:

1. why I did not get sd by applying the first syntax?
2. why is the second syntax not workable?  I learned this syntax from stackoverflow, and it worked with the following data frame,

   ```r
   x3 <- read.table(text = "  id1 id2 val1 val2
   1   a   x    1    9
   2   a   x    2    4
   3   a   y    3    NA
   4   a   y    4    NA
   5   b   x    1    NA
   6   b   y    4    NA
   7   b   x    3    9
   8   b   y    2    8", header = TRUE)
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`, where we pass the grouping columns in `group_by` and the columns to `summarise` in `summarise` with `across`

```
library(dplyr) #1.0.0
x3 %>%
   group_by(id1, id2) %>% 
   summarise(across(starts_with('val'),  
        list(mean = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE) , sd = ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE))))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   id1 [2]
#  id1   id2   val1_mean val1_sd val2_mean val2_sd
#  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 a     x           1.5   0.707       6.5    3.54
#2 a     y           3.5   0.707     NaN     NA   
#3 b     x           2     1.41        9     NA   
#4 b     y           3     1.41        8     NA
```

If the version of `dplyr` is < 1.0.0, we can use `summarise_at`

```
x3 %>%
   group_by(id1, id2) %>%  
   summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), list(mean = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), 
              sd = ~ sd(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

With `aggregate`, the error we get because of the `NA` elements and it uses by default `na.action = na.drop` removing the row if there is any NA in that row.  Either specify `na.action = na.pass` or `NULL` and this would resolve that issue.  But, having multiple functions to be applied with `c`, it will result in a `matrix` column.  Inorder to have normal `data.frame`, columns, we can wrap with `data.frame` in `do.call`

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ id1 + id2, data = x3, FUN = function(x) 
   c(avg = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), SD= sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)), na.action = NULL))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, in do.call(), what is data.frame?  Is it the data.frame I want to create?

Comment: I also applied your dplyr approach to my data.frame.  I still did not get sd columns.

Comment: @lennylin. The output from `aggregate` is a `data.frame`, but some columns are matrices because we have multiple functions on the same columns If you check the `str(aggregate(. ~ id1 + id2, data = x3, FUN = function(x) 
   c(avg = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), SD= sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)), na.action = NULL))` you will find the issue.  So, I wrapped with `data.frame` in `do.call` to make those matrix as indepdent columns

Comment: @lennylin i used `dplyr 1.0.0`.  if your version is below that, you can use `summarise_at`, updated the post

Comment: @ akrun, I am using `dplyr 1.0.0`  with `R 4.0.2`.  I also tried summarise_at, I got an error message: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: @lennylin is it the same data you showed in the post ('x3').  I am using R 4.0 with dplyr 1.0.0.  Both the codes are working for me though

Comment: @akun, no, I am working with a data frame x with 5753 observations of 4 variables.  I found solutions work well with x3, but not mine.

Comment: @lennylin then, it must be either an issue with type of columns i.e. not numeric columns used in summarise or NA only cases?  Without a small reproducible example with `dput`, it is not clear

Comment: @ akrun, I am new to `dput`.  anyway, here is a structure:
`> str(x3)
'data.frame': 5753 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ date                  : Date, format: "2016-09-26" "2016-12-12" "2016-09-13" "2016-05-23" ...
 $ Depth                 : chr  "01~05m" "01~05m" "01~05m" "01~10m" ...
 $ Chlorophyll_a         : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Dissolved_Oxygen_Field: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
> `

Comment: @lennylin if you do `dput(droplevels(head(iris, 20)))`, it will print the structure of the first 20 rows.  Similarly in your case it would be `dput(droplevels(head(x3, 20)))`. From the `str`, I see a lot of NA elements. i.e. for a particular group, there may be only NAs

Comment: @lennylin i also tried with changing some elements to NA ,so that it is all NA, but it is still working with the data.  `x3$val2[1:2] <- NA`

Comment: yes, there are 5622 NA in var1, 5049 NA in var2 out of 5753 obs.

Comment: @lennylin, but the code is working even when groups are having all NAs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217231/discussion-between-lennylin-and-akrun).

Comment: In conclusion, I was advised not using aggregate() to do with my data frame because there are so many NA, but use `group_by()` and `summarise()` approach.